# How to check access for Guest in unit tests in Yii?

Tags: php, unit-testing, authentication, yii

I have an application written in Yii 1.1.8.

I am currently developing a set of unit tests to cover user access rights. I am using yii-rights module and I discovered one odd thing about it.

```
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($operation)
```

always returns false in unit tests (not when running app in the borwser).

I found a kind of a workaround, I am calling the

```
Yii::app()->getAuthManager()->checkAccess($operation, $userId)
```

to check access for authenticated user, but there is one problem - I have some authItems that Guest users need to have access to. And my tests are failing, because Guest user has no id, so I can't call CheckAccess() from CDbAuthManager class. checkAccess() from CWebUser also fails because of some bug.

Before every test I call the authentication code and it works - access is granted (or rejected, depending on rights config) for authenticated users properly and Yii::app()->user is set properly too.

So my question is: how can I make Yii::app()->user->checkAccess($operation) work in unit tests, or is there any way to get some kind of id of guest user to use the other checkAccess() function? Or is there any other way of checking access that I don'tknow about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found what to do. It was quite simple actually.

I gave only Guest role to one user, I authenticate as this user and therefore I can get Guest user id :D.

Hope this helps someone :). If anyone knows of better way I will be to happy to read it :D.

Answer (score 1):

it's a liitle old but may help others, you can simply add a role for guest in defualtRoles of authManager

```
'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
        'defaultRoles'=>array('Guest'),
    ),
```

so don't need to add a user for guest